# Как сделать сервак на своем компьютере?

Tags: сервер

Как сделать сервер на своем компьютере?
Хочу запустить сайт со своего компа!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам понадобится "белый" IP, он же частный (приватный). Или же договориться с провайдером, чтобы он настроил NAT для вас, но это более сложный подход, точнее не всегда приемлемый для провайдера.
Затем ставите Denwer, XAMPP или другие сборки (потому, что просто).
По инструкции укладываете свой сайт в нужную директорию и все готово.

Также можно заказать под это дело ДНС имя на свой адрес, регистраторов полным полно.

Вот собственно и всё, за подробностями обращайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

А некоторые провайдеры дают возможность зарегать у них поддомен вида tra-ta-ta.prov.ru, а уже сделать линки на него можно с любых других доменов. Просто позвоните в поддержку провайдера и узнайте.